# Keep laravel queue:work running while in jailshell

Tags: laravel, cron, jail-shell

I'm having issues keeping the queue:work command running on my server. I tried nohup, but as soon as I close the terminal (which times out every 5 minutes or so no matter what I've tried) the process goes away.

I thought about running a script in cron to kick off the nohup command, however that runs in jailshell too so I have no way of seeing if the process is still running from a previous cron or not and I don't want a potential 20k copies of this running because it's trying to kick off every minute.

I also don't have access to install software to install Supervisord.

So, what other solutions can I use to ensure this stays running?

**EDIT** I contacted the support for my host, and pretty much it looks like there are no real alternatives for me. I think I'm going to have to set this project up on Linode, or rework things to not have queuing tasks.

Comment: I wouldn't bother using shared hosting for a Laravel application these days, not when you can get a VPS on Digital Ocean or Linode for a similar price.

Comment: I have a reseller amount so hosting another site on my account doesn't cost extra. But yeah, Laravel is complicated enough that it's probably worth getting something dedicated.

Comment: You could switch to the sync driver, but that defeats the purpose of having a queue in the first place.

Comment: Yeah. The main purpose I'm using queues is because I'm sending messages to pushover, which you need to limit how often you send them, so this was the best way I could think to do that. Plus the other benefits of queues. Since I'm using them I have queued up a few things, so if I turned off queueing then I'd have to change some things.

Comment: Only other solution I can think of is to move the queue workers to a third-party service - for example, use Amazon SQS as the queue and have the worker run on an EC2 instance, but that involves paying for that third-party service anyway so you're probably better off sticking with a VPS anyway.

Comment: @MasterZwhat did you end up doing? I'm having the same problem but I feel close to a solution. The issue now is that a jailshelled CRON cannot see other processes running on the machine (VPS), which I can see with SSH

Comment: @clod986 I setup a web server on Linode. :D

Comment: @MasterZ I actually managed to find a solution after writing you today: my hosting provider contacted cPanel developers and changed the SHELL variable!!! I wrote an answer hoping to help others with the same problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem resides in the shell configuration, because the command `ps` is rewritten to show only the children process.

The solution is to ask your hosting provider (or change it yourself if allowed) to set this variable:

```
SHELL="/bin/bash"
```

This simple fix allowed me to have the function working properly.

Now my `Kernel.php` looks as follows:

```
$command = "ps faux | grep queue:work";

exec($command, $task_list);
// Process are duplicate in ps and show also the command as two single lines
$running_process = (count($task_list) / 2) - 1;

if($running_process < 1)
    $schedule->command('queue:work --queue=high,low --tries=3')
        ->everyMinute();
else if($running_process > 5)
    // If too many are active, restart everything to avoid overload
    $schedule->call(function(){
        Artisan::call('queue:restart');
    })->everyMinute();
```

This code makes sure that at least one worker is always running, and at the same time forces a `restart` if you have more that 5 workers active.